# passing data to the controller through ajax from view

Tags: ajax, controller, pagination, cakephp-2.0

I have a page

http://www.mysite.com/discusssion/name_of_topic/page:1

At the click of a button in this view, I want to redirect the param (i.e the url) to a controller and fetch the data.
the url is:
http://www.mysite.com/discusssion/name_of_topic/page:2

I am writing an ajax function to call a controller and fetch the data but that is not working from me. Here is my ajax function

```
$("#loadbut").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : "/discussion/"+$topic+"/page:2",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.success) {
                pr(data);
                exit();
            } else {
                console.log(response.data, response.code);
            }
        }
    });

});'
```

How can I make this work, any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Few things i would try

1. Assuming that is 1:1 the code you have, add
2. Install or use something like firebug to view the request made. Check the address that it's right.
3. Make sure your controller action works as intended. Does it really return a valid json-response.

That's about as much as I can help without more info.

Answer (score 0):

Few things you need to clarify/do:

1. This `$topic` variable, where do you define it? Is it php? If so, you're mixing it up with js, it should be `url : "/discussion/<?=$topic?>/page:2"`
2. There's a `pr(data);exit;` in the response, is that php again?
3. Check the url the ajax is making the request, either with firebug (or something similar) or with a `console.log(url)` to see where it goes.
4. If you execute the ajax url in the browser (put **::your_url::/discusion/::name_of_topic::/page:2** in the address bar), the answer you receive is what you are expecting from the ajax request

It's difficult to know the problem if you don't tell us what kind of error you're receiving. Does it simply not work without any display? What does firebug says?

Comment: $topic is the variable I pass to the view from the controller. and this  pr(data);exit; is nothing it was just a check to know whether the ajax function is called or not. And my ajax funtion is not working.

Comment: yes, that's clear, but it's a php variable and you're using it in a js function, why is that?

Comment: i want to make a URL and for that i need that $topic variable

Comment: But it's a _php_ variable, to use it in js you have to adjust your code like I pointed in the answer. And the pr() and exit; definitely have to go or you'll have js errors. There's no way that function is going to work if you keep mixing php and js like that